# Compare 2 columns rows if date is greater then update "Yes" else "No"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with From date and Through columns with dates. I have one more column is Eligible. So if Through column's value is greater than From date column's value, Eligible column rows has to be updated Yes otherwise No. Kindly help me with this logic in sql server.

```
WHILE @MyDate > DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        MI.Suffix as [Mem Sfx], 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), EB.Eligibility_Date, 101) as [From],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), MI.EOI_Termination_Date, 101) as [Through],
        'No' AS Eligible, 
        SG.SubGroupId as Subgroup, 
        EB.Plan_ID as [Plan],
        '00' + RIGHT('123658' + CAST('00' AS VARCHAR(8)), 8) Product  
    FROM [dbo].[Members.Indicative] MI 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Eligibilty] EB ON EB.Subscriber_ID = MI.Subscriber_ID 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Subgroup] SG ON SG.Subscriber_ID=MI.Subscriber_ID  
    order by MI.Suffix
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case..when` statement

```
case when CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), EB.Eligibility_Date, 101) <
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), MI.EOI_Termination_Date, 101) then
      'Yes'
else
      'No'
end as [Eligible]
```